# Javascript regex replace best practice

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an expression like that:

```
expr {name1} + {name2} - ({name3}*{name4})
```

Now, I also get an object like that a:13 , b:11 , c:5
I know that this is an arithmetic expression.
Now I do as follow :

```
for (var ff = 0; ff < fields.length; ff++) {
   var name = cfg.fields[ff];
   var re = new RegExp("{" + name + "}", "g");
   expr = expr.replace(re, data[name]);
}

result = eval(expr);
```

fields is an array containing possible matched to what's inside the {}
data[name] contains the replacement data

Now , I see that the eval takes a lot less than the creating and replacing of the regex.

But still I'm getting poor performance.
Can anyone help with how to improve this and get better runtime?

Comment: I guess `expr = expr.replace(/\{(.)\}/g, function(m, v) { return data[v]; });` would be more elegant.

Comment: more elegant or faster?

Comment: Agree with @FelixKling, just execute all the replacements at once.

Comment: try it: http://jsperf.com/ . I can't say because you only showed the replacement of one variable. I don't know what you are doing with the others. Speed shouldn't be a concern for you at that moment though. I bet that this part is not the bottleneck of your app.

Comment: Is is actually , since this line is being executed many many times.
Just updated to be more specific.

Comment: the for-loop is useless with the code provided by FelixKling

Comment: Especially note that with the loop, you are creating many regexs, which all need to be compiled etc.  The version in the first comment here has 1 regex that covers all forms of `{...}`

Comment: Is that supposed to be `/\{(.+?)\}/g` (added `+`) or am I just being dense here?

Comment: @JosephMarikle Potentially, though the examples given are all 1 character in length

Comment: @JosephMarikle the first code provided by OP was only about one letter for the names like {a}, {b}

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to imply your answer and use it in my code. could you please write an answer using your code inside mine?

Comment: @user816004 Replace your entire `for` loop with the first comment

Comment: @user816004 replace your for-loop with the code provided by the first comment of FelixKling